# timezone change resets after reboot ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, dpkg, timezone

I am trying to change my timezone from HKT to JST or any other timezone for that using the most commonly used command that I can find `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

This successfully changes the timezone to JST. But upon reboot it reverts to HKT.
I cannot seem to find any solid answers to this other than use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think reconfiguring the tzdata is the right thing to do.
On my system, I've set the timezone by right clicking on the time in the window manager and selecting 'Time and Date Settings'.

There is also a file /etc/timezone -- edit that with the right information -- Asia/Tokyo, I think.

The other thing is to make sure /etc/localtime is hard linked to the right file under /usr/share/zoneinfo/, probably /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo .